# How do I create a plot that represents a sum of sinusoids without a loop?

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization

How can I make a simple plot of function `y = sin(x) + sin(3x) + ... + sin(100x)` without using any loops?

Comment: The last element of the sum should be `sin(101x)`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using a call to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to generate the right points to be applied per sinusoid, then using a [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) call to sum all of the sinusoids for each point.  You'd then plot this normally.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
x = -5:0.01:5; %// Define x points here
pts = bsxfun(@times, 1:2:101, x(:)); %// Generate a grid of points
y = sum(sin(pts), 2); %// Compute the y values for each x value
plot(x(:),y); %// Plot the result
```

The first line of code generates a set of `x` values that you wish to plot. The next line of code generates a 2D grid of points.  Each row applies `x, 3*x, 5*x, ..., 101*x` for one particular point in `x`.  Each column represents one unique `x` point.  As such, when we use `sum` (next line), we also apply the `sin` operator to each of these individual points on the grid, then go ahead and sum over each row to produce the output for each unique point of `x`.  We then plot the results.

Note that I used `x(:)` to unroll the `x` vector so that it's a column vector.  This is needed for the code to work.  This also allows you to make `x` a row or column vector and the code will still work.

This is the plot I get:

[image]

Comment: I've made a mistake. The function was `sin(x)+sin(2x)+...+sin(100x)`. Anyway, it's easy to fix in a code. Thank you!

Comment: ah I see.  Just change the `1:2:101` to `1:100`.  You're welcome :) If you no longer need help, please consider accepting my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `cumsum`.

```
    octave:1> x = 1;
    octave:2> sin(x)
    ans =    0.841470984807897
    octave:3> sin(x*1)
    ans =    0.841470984807897
    octave:4> sin(x*1) + sin(x*2)
    ans =     1.75076841163358
    octave:5> sin(x*1) + sin(x*2) + sin(x*3)
    ans =     1.89188841969345
    octave:6> cumsum(sin(x * (1:3)))
    ans =

         0.841470984807897      1.75076841163358      1.89188841969345
```

Comment: That only solves this for one point.  Could you generalize this to `x` being a vector of points?  The OP wants to plot this function.

Comment: The question is not clear... of source `x` can be a vector too. `sin = @(x) cumsum(sin(x))(end)` _(note that matlab doesn't support expression indexing)_

Comment: Well... I don't think you need `cumsum` at all.  Just use `sum` because the amount of sinusoidal functions can be inferred from the input vector (`1:3` in your case).

Comment: BTW, forgive me for stalking, but I came to this page when I went to your profile: https://github.com/repelem/repelem/blob/master/repelem.m - nice work :)